# Event listener only applying to last created element

Tags: javascript, class, dom

I am trying to generate 5 squares on the screen & when i hover my mouse over one of them, the background colour of the square changes to black. I apply a "hit" class to the element after the mouse has been hovered over it. The hit class is only applied to the last square that has been generated. but not for any others. I have looked at some other stackoverflow questions which I am aware are similar to mine but I cannot seem to find an answer as i am not modifying innerHTML within my javaScript code.

I cannot use JQuery in this project.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Etch A Sketch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>

<div id="grid">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript code:

```
let grid = document.querySelector("#grid"); //The grid is the border that surrounds all of the squares


for (i=0; i < 5; i++) {
square = document.createElement("div");
square.classList.add("square"); //The "square" class creates the square out of the div
grid.appendChild(square);
}

square.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
  square.classList.add("hit"); //The "hit" class just changes the background color of the square to black
})
```

CSS code:

```
.square {
  display: inline-grid;
  width: 31px;
  height: 31px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.hit {
  background-color: black;
}


#grid {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -250px;
    margin-left: -250px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 3px solid black;
}​
```

Comment: add the event listener in the loop, and declare your square using `let` so it has blocked scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class is only being applied to the last element because you are adding the event listener outside of the loop, so it is only applying it to the last instance of `square`. Also please note that you should declare your variable before using it. In your example, you use `square` without ever initializing it. See here:

```js
let grid = document.querySelector("#grid"); //The grid is the border that surrounds all of the squares


for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  let square = document.createElement("div");
  square.classList.add("square"); //The "square" class creates the square out of the div
  grid.appendChild(square);

  square.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    square.classList.add("hit"); //The "hit" class just changes the background color of the square to black
  })
}
```

```css
.square {
  display: inline-grid;
  width: 31px;
  height: 31px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.hit {
  background-color: black;
}

#grid {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -250px;
  margin-left: -250px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

​
```

```html
<div id="grid"></div>
```